# Spinner scrolls to top when onLongPress or scrolling slowly

Tags: android, spinner, gesture, android-scroll

I have a spinner with a LOOONG list of items. What I noticed is that whenever I try to scroll the spinner items SLOWLY, it suddenly takes me back to the top of the spinner selection. I'm just using a standard Spinner with a simple ArrayAdapter. It's not really an issue, but it's kinda annoying that whenever a user would scroll slowly, the selection resets all the way to the top. You can fling the list, but if you scroll slowly, keeping your finger on the screen, it scrolls back up to the top of the list.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Why does it occur? Is there a way to "fix" this issue?

Note: The problem I have is only on a Spinner.

Comment: Found any solution ?

Comment: Perhaps related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065626

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and removing the `app:popupTheme` attribute fixed it. Check this comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065626#comment15.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by the following method.

- API level 22 or lower: Use `app:popupTheme`
- API level 23 or higher: Use `android:popupTheme`

*res/layout/spinner.xml*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_spinner_margin_right"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

*res/layout-v23/spinner.xml*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/toolbar_spinner_margin_right"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

*res/layout/activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <include layout="@layout/spinner" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: spinner button color is black]

And to solve an issue where the spinner button color is black in API level 19 or lower, you need to add the following code:

*Kotlin*

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    val spinnerDrawable = spinner.background.constantState.newDrawable()
    spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        spinner.background = spinnerDrawable
    } else {
        spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable)
    }
}
```

*Java*

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Drawable spinnerDrawable = spinner.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
    spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        spinner.setBackground(spinnerDrawable);
    } else {
        spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable);
    }
}
```